# imgId.style.webkitTransform = tString; not working

Tags: javascript

The below javascript is called on gesturechange event of an image.In this code everything works fine except the line  imgId.style.webkitTransform = tString;
transform is not happening after getting the scaling value.

function getAngleAndScale(e) {

```
var imgId = e.target.id;
alert(imgId);
var scale = 1;
var newScale;

// Don't zoom or rotate the whole screen
e.preventDefault();

newScale = scale * e.scale;

var tString = "scale(" + newScale + ")";


imgId.style.webkitTransform = tString;

 }
```

any other way to do this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR prefixed names (of CSS properties) should have first letter uppercased.

CSS: -webkit-transform

JS: WebkitTransform

Comment: Since `imgId = e.target.id` you are trying to update `e.target.id.style`. Are you sure, this is what you want? Maybe, `e.target.style` better matches your purpose.

Comment: yeah based on id of the image i am trying to zoomin and zoomout an image.if i hard code the image id then it is working fine. document.getElementById("imgcertificate").style.webkitTransform = tString; this is working fine.but imgId.style.webkitTransform = tString;this is not working.

Comment: Image's id doesn't have `style` property -- only the image itself has it!